# How to query more than 800 fields in query using Bulk load query

Tags: query, fields, bulk, backup

I'm working in a custom backup application using Mulesoft, basically I want to make a full backup of all custom sobjects of different Salesforce instances.

The main issue is I can't create a BULK load with more than 800 records in my query because I'm getting

**Failed: ClientInputError : Failed to read query. Exceeded max size limit of 20000 with response size 20001**

I would like to know if is there any way to query all fields, for now my only solution I guess is split the query in many different request and then append the results in one last file but I would like to skip this if there's something better.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [SOQL Limits Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm). There's a number of limitations that will prevent you from exporting objects of this size in one go, including total character limit, number of large text area fields, total response size, etc. If you want to export *all* the records just once, the easiest way is to go to **Setup > Data Management > Data Export** and choose the object to export. You can only perform this type of export once per week/month depending on your edition. Otherwise, you will need to break your query up into multiple queries.

Comment: In the end I guess the only way is split the query and merge the columns to generate an csv output. For now I will make it using Mulesoft